# Change the position of imported animation

Tags: animation

how can I position the "sitting/typing" animation (image 2) so that the feet align with the "idle" animation (image 1)?

I tried to delete the mixamorig.Hips Location keyframes and insert new keyframes but the armature keeps going back to the position it was before.

[image]
[image]

Here is the blender file:
[image]

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: you can either move and keyframe the root bone, if there's one, or you can use the Graph Editor to move all the bones on Y, until the feet position match

Comment: please share your file or at least the armature: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hi @moonboots, blend-exchange took too long so I uploaded it on CGTrader https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/architectural/engineering/testtesttesttesttest-77da281d-3d25-48a0-ad35-d2ebf3859f13

Comment: hello could you please use another platform? I can't get your file here for some reason...

Comment: @moonboots It worked now and I added the file to my post.

Comment: @A Bren I can't see any bones, only empties, plus you have a lot of actions, could you please send the armature and tell which are the 2 actions you're refering to?